# how to get selection range from excel 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel

i cant get selection range from excel. i am using below code block and i can get active sheet like this. but i need only selection range. how can i do this?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ExWorksheet = ExApp.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range activeSheet = ExWorksheet.UsedRange as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
```

thanks for advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The selection is a property of the Application, so you should use something like:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SelectedRange = ExApp.Selection as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
```

Just be careful that the object returned by Selection could be something different fromn a Range (e.g. it could be a Chart), so you should check for null values of SelectedRange.

Comment: this is work. but i also can do like this:   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range selectedRange = ExApp.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection;

Comment: thanks, how can i understand selected range is empty, Even if i select a single cell that does not empty or null.

Comment: do tou mean that yoy want to check whether the selected cell does not contain anything?

Comment: actually no, i wanted to know selected range size and if it is smaller than 1, i want to use UserRange. So i solve this problem like this - ((dynamic)selectedRange).Count > 1